# Porting from VxWorks to Quadros/RTXC

Tags: vxworks

I am porting an embedded application code base from 'Vxworks' to 'RTXC/Quadros'. What is the equivalent of 'semMCreate' vxworks API in Quadros ?

Answer (score 1):

semMCreate is the vxworks routine used to create a mutex semaphore. These are created dynamically at runtime

I have not used Quadros RTXC, however it appears that objects such as this are created statically, based on configuration (in a similar fashion to the vxworks microkernel).

You should search for Mutex Objects in your user guide.